# Extract and manipulate data from csv - finding unique values and displaying corresponding data from another column

Tags: python, excel

I have a csv that looks like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.10.1 | Text A |
| 192.168.10.1 | Text B |
| 192.168.10.1 | Text C |
| 192.168.10.2 | Text A |
| 192.168.10.3 | Text B |
| 192.168.10.3 | Text C |
| 192.168.10.4 | Text A |
| 192.168.10.4 | Text C |

The intended result would be:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Text A | 192.168.10.1 |
|  | 192.168.10.2 |
|  | 192.168.10.4 |
| Text B | 192.168.10.1 |
|  | 192.168.10.3 |
| Text C | 192.168.10.1 |
|  | 192.168.10.3 |
|  | 192.168.10.4 |

This could be either something in Excel or ideally something that I can do using python (pandas)?

Thanks very much for any kind response,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the groupby function of pandas for this. After reading the csv into python as a dataframe, you can run the following command:

```
final = df.groupby(['Column B'])
```

You may refer to the following documentation for the same: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html